# Python 2.7 - csv.Error: sequence expected

Tags: json, python-2.7, csv

I am making an API call to AWS using `Python` and `boto3`. The response is returned in `JSON`, so I am writing the `JSON` response to a file. Then, I need to open the `JSON` file and convert it to a  `csv` file. When I run my code, I am getting the above error. Below is my code, sample `JSON`, and the traceback.

**Code:**

```
def ResponseConvert():
    dynamo = boto3.client('dynamodb',
        region_name='xxxxxx',
        aws_access_key_id='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
        aws_secret_access_key='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')

    response = dynamo.scan(
    TableName='XXXXXXXXX'
    )
    with open('vuln_data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(response, outfile, indent=4)

    f = open('vuln_data.json')
    data = json.load(f)
    f.close()

    writer = csv.writer(open('vuln_data.csv', 'wb+'))

    writer.writerow(data.iterkeys())
    for row in data:
        writer.writerow(row.itervalues())

ResponseConvert()
```

**JSON:**

```
{
"Count": 55,
"Items": [
    {
        "CVSS_SCORE": {
            "S": "3.5"
        },
        "AMI_ID": {
            "S": "ami-xxxxxxx"
        },
        "OS": {
            "S": "Ubuntu / Tiny Core Linux / Linux 2.6.x"
        },
        "PATCHES": {
            "S": "xxxxxxx"
        }
    },
    {
        "CVSS_SCORE": {
            "S": "3.5"
        },
        "AMI_ID": {
            "S": "ami-xxxxxxxx"
        },
        "OS": {
            "S": "CentOS Linux 7.3.1611"
        },
        "PATCHES": {
            "S": "xxxxxxx"
        }
      }
   ]
}
```

**Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "response_convert.py", line 20, in <module>
    ResponseConvert()
  File "response_vonvert.py", line 16, in ResponseConvert
    writer.writerow(data.iterkeys())
_csv.Error: sequence expected
```

Comment: Does it work with `data.keys()` instead of `data.iterkeys()` (and likewise `data.values()` instead of `data.itervalues()`)?

Comment: I think you need to rethink that `for` loop. I'm not sure what to tell you because I'm not sure exactly what you expect it to do. But note that looping over a dict gives you the dict keys, so `row` is to going to be a key of the `data` dict. That doesn't look like what you want.

Comment: @glibdud, when I do that, I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
    writer.writerow(row.values())
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'values'`

Comment: @gilbdud I would like each key to be its own column in the csv file, and have all the values be written to rows under the appropriate columns. Does that make sense?